# Rails 4 testing nested resources with multiple URL params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I have been at this for a few hours, still can't figure it out. I have 2 tests on 2 actions on a nested resources controller. `requests` is the parent resources route, and `response` is the nested resources route.

These 2 tests give me a `no route matches` error. Does not make sense. In the first test, it tries to run the `update` action instead of the `edit`. Here are my tests:

```
test "should get edit" do
  assert_routing edit_request_response_path(@myresponse.request_id, @myresponse), { :controller => "responses", :action => "edit", :request_id => @myresponse.request_id.to_s, :id => @myresponse.id.to_s }
  get :edit, params: { id: @myresponse, request_id: @myresponse.request_id }
  assert_response :success
end

test "should update response" do
  post :update, :request_id => @myresponse.request_id, response: { body: @myresponse.body, request_id: @myresponse.request_id, status: @myresponse.status, subject: @myresponse.subject, user_id: @myresponse.user_id }
  assert_redirected_to response_path(assigns(:response))
end
```

Here are the errors:

```
3) Error:
ResponsesControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"responses", :params=>{:id=>"980190962", :request_id=>"999788447"}}
test/controllers/responses_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:ResponsesControllerTest>'


4) Error:
ResponsesControllerTest#test_should_update_response:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"responses", :request_id=>"999788447", :response=>{:body=>"This is the body", :request_id=>"999788447", :status=>"draft", :subject=>"This is the subject", :user_id=>"175178709"}}
test/controllers/responses_controller_test.rb:48:in `block in <class:ResponsesControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you might want to use shallow nesting since there is no reason to go through `request` if you can get to a response by `/response/:id`.

```
resources :requests, shallow: true do
  resources :response
end
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

---

```
test "should get edit" do
  assert_routing edit_response_path(@myresponse), { :controller => "responses", :action => "edit", :id => @myresponse.id.to_s }
  get :edit, params: { id: @myresponse, request_id: @myresponse.request_id }
  assert_response :success
end
```

However naming your business logic objects `Request` and `Response` is a big misstake. These are already key concepts in Rails which correspond to the request from the client and the response sent to the client by rails.

You will end up confusing yourself and any poor sucker that has to work on the project. Plus you will end up masking the `request` and `response` methods that are pretty important parts of the ActionController API.

Use some other synonym instead.